# UIView Icon Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage, core-animation

Im trying to do burst animation when the user clicks a view. Im bursting the view into circular pieces when the user clicks a specific view. So I have converted the uiview to uiimage as follows,

```
   - (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
        [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

        UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return img;
    }
```

Then I have broken the uiimage to pieces  as follows,

```
-(void)splitImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    CGFloat imgWidth = image.size.width/2;
    CGFloat imgheight = image.size.height;
    CGRect leftImgFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, imgWidth, imgheight);
    CGRect rightImgFrame = CGRectMake(imgWidth, 0, imgWidth, imgheight);

    CGImageRef left = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, leftImgFrame);
    CGImageRef right = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, rightImgFrame);

    UIImage* leftImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:left];
    UIImage* rightImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:right];

    CGImageRelease(left);
    CGImageRelease(right);
}
```

But there are certain issues im facing while doing it.

1. Im able to break the uiimage into only two pieces but not into
   dynamic pieces.
2. How can i show like then uiview is bursting into circular pieces with these broken uiimages?

**UPDATE:**
Following is my updated code...

```
-(void)startAnimation{


    //Add the initial circle
//    UIView* circleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 60, 60)];
    UIView *circleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.submit.bounds];

    circleView.bounds = self.submit.bounds;

    CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    //set colors
    [circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
    [circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
    [circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:circleView.bounds] CGPath]];
    [circleView.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];
    [self.view addSubview:circleView];

    //Animate circle
    [circleView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0)];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
        [circleView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        circleView.hidden = YES;
        //start next animation
        [self createIconAnimation];
    }];
}

-(void)createIconAnimation{

    //load icon which pops up
    UIImageView* iconImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_tick"]];
    iconImage.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 60, 60);
    iconImage.bounds = self.submit.bounds;
    [iconImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0)];
    [self.view addSubview:iconImage];

    //animate icon
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/1.5 animations:^{
        iconImage.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.1, 1.1);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/2 animations:^{
            iconImage.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9, 0.9);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/2 animations:^{
                iconImage.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            }];
        }];
    }];


    //add circles around the icon
    int numberOfCircles = 20;
    CGPoint center = iconImage.center;
    float radius= 35;
    BOOL isBig = YES;;
    for (int i = 0; i<numberOfCircles; i++) {

        float x = radius*cos(M_PI/numberOfCircles*i*2) + center.x;
        float y = radius*sin(M_PI/numberOfCircles*i*2) + center.y;

        float circleRadius = 10;
        if (isBig) {
            circleRadius = 5;
            isBig = NO;
        }else{
            isBig = YES;
        }

        UIView* circleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, circleRadius, circleRadius)];
        CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        [circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
        [circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
        [circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:circleView.bounds] CGPath]];
        [circleView.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];
        [self.view addSubview:circleView];

        //animate circles
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            [circleView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(radius/3*cos(M_PI/numberOfCircles*i*2), radius/3*sin(M_PI/numberOfCircles*i*2))];
            [circleView setTransform:CGAffineTransformScale(circleView.transform, 0.01, 0.01)];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            circleView.hidden = YES;
        }];


    }

}
```

The animation has to be on top of the self.submit button but it is not positioned on top of it

Comment: can you give examples how it should look like? The task you are looking for is not easy to achieve since it maybe needs 3d features if you want a fancy explosion or whatever. I once tried this with voronoi patterns. It worked quite well but the 3d effect was a pain

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ChadCSong/ShineButton/master/demo_shine_others.gif

Comment: Im trying to do it like the above view

Comment: these animations consist of different stages. First the circle grows, then the circle disappears and the icon appears together with the circles around the icon. give me 30 mins and i will post it as an answer

Comment: ya please... thank you so much in advance

Comment: replace `circleView.bounds = self.submit.bounds;` with `circleView.frame = self.submit.frame;` and `iconImage.bounds = self.submit.bounds;` with `iconImage.frame = self.submit.frame;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, just add this code to your view controller. It gives you this result:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/PhcIv]

Just play around with the colors and the animations to get your desired result.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self startAnimation];

}

-(void)startAnimation{

    //Add the initial circle
    UIView* circleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 60, 60)];
    CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    //set colors
    [circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
    [circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
    [circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:circleView.bounds] CGPath]];
    [circleView.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];
    [self.view addSubview:circleView];

    //Animate circle
    [circleView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0)];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
        [circleView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        circleView.hidden = YES;
        //start next animation
        [self createIconAnimation];
    }];
}

-(void)createIconAnimation{

    //load icon which pops up
    UIImageView* iconImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Untitled"]];
    iconImage.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 60, 60);
    [iconImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0)];
    [self.view addSubview:iconImage];

    //animate icon
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/1.5 animations:^{
        iconImage.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.1, 1.1);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/2 animations:^{
            iconImage.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9, 0.9);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3/2 animations:^{
                iconImage.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            }];
        }];
    }];


    //add circles around the icon
    int numberOfCircles = 20;
    CGPoint center = iconImage.center;
    float radius= 35;
    BOOL isBig = YES;;
    for (int i = 0; i<numberOfCircles; i++) {

        float x = radius*cos(M_PI/numberOfCircles*i*2) + center.x;
        float y = radius*sin(M_PI/numberOfCircles*i*2) + center.y;

        float circleRadius = 10;
        if (isBig) {
            circleRadius = 5;
            isBig = NO;
        }else{
            isBig = YES;
        }

        UIView* circleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, circleRadius, circleRadius)];
        CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        [circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
        [circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
        [circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:circleView.bounds] CGPath]];
        [circleView.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];
        [self.view addSubview:circleView];

        //animate circles
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            [circleView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(radius/3*cos(M_PI/numberOfCircles*i*2), radius/3*sin(M_PI/numberOfCircles*i*2))];
            [circleView setTransform:CGAffineTransformScale(circleView.transform, 0.01, 0.01)];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            circleView.hidden = YES;
        }];


    }

}



@end
```

Comment: Thank you bro..i will try it and let you know if i face any complications

Comment: can you please give me the source code? because circles are not appearing bro

Comment: im using it with uiview

Comment: you have to use it within an UIViewController, like i edited it now

Comment: ui view that im using is bound within uiviewcontroller

Comment: then replace everywhere self.view with self then it should work

Comment: it works now bro..thank you so much...but after animation, the uiview is displaced upwards

Comment: bro..what is    iconImage.frame = CGRectMake(100, 50, 60, 60);... I have replaced it with self.submit.iconImage.frame = CGRectMake(100, 50, 60, 60); so that the circles will be visible over the submit button but it is showing the circles on top of screen

Comment: replace `[self.view addSubview:circleView];` with `[self.view insertSubview:circleView belowSubview:iconImage];`